# What happens to render view call when filter returns false?

Tags: grails, view, filter

I have a filter that does some check and returns false based on that check failure. But, before it returns false it renders error view that should be displayed to user in case of such errors. Instead, a blank page is displayed with error code 404. Note that url contains controller and action that do not exists so normally a 404 would make sense but since i have applied a global filter here which gets called and makes the render call, i am concerned about that render call which didnt materialized.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share code ?

I guess you try to render something that does not exist.

Following code works for me

```
    def filters = {
       before = { Map model ->
                ...
                render (view: '/access-denied')
                return false

    }
```

and it renders access-denied.gsp

Also usually I am not rendering view in this kind of case, Instead I am redirecting  it something like following

```
            before = { Map model ->
                ...
                redirect(uri: '/access-denied')
                return false
            }
```

Comment: i am not allowed to redirect to new location according to requirement. Here are some things that differ from your case. First, filter extends base controller. here, filter calls controller's method that makes render call. Second, this controller lies in other plugin project that is added to main grails project where this filter lies. Now, the view file exists in that plugin project but i dont think that should be an issue as i am doing many render calls to view files over there and they all work.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by 'filter extends base controller'. Can you share code of your filter ?

Comment: `class MainFilters extends BaseController {
def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            if (!init()) {
                doResponse(owner, request, response, params)
                return false
            }

            return true
        }
        after = { Map model ->
            println "after called with model "+model.inspect()
        }
    }
}

boolean doResponse(webFilter, request, response, params) {
   webFilter.render(view: "/error/erlink")
    return false
}
}`

Comment: I still think that view can not be found!

Try to add plugin parameter to render method
webFilter.render(plugin: 'yourPluginName',view: "/error/erlink")
and make sure that path of view (i.e. "/error/erlink") is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward to render a view in a filter. E.g.

```
all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
    before = {  
        if(requirePost &&  !"post".equalsIgnoreCase(request.method)) {
            response.status = 405
            response.setHeader('Access','POST');
            forward(controller: 'page', action: 'http405')
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

This way the URL does not change.